# SqlTableDependency no dispara evento onChange en WindowsForms pero sí en aplicación de consola

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms, sqltabledependency

Estoy tratando de realizar una aplicación para imprimir tickets de venta. La idea es que el programa detecte cambios en la tabla Venta de la base de datos para que en cuanto se inserte un registro llame a la función para imprimir. El problema es que el evento Change no se dispara. No es un problema de conexión entre SqlTableDependency y la base de datos ya que no marca ningún error al ejecutar el método Start() de SqlTableDependency.

He probado establecer esta misma conexión en una aplicación de consola y ahí los cambios son detectados sin problema alguno. ¿Alguien tiene idea de que está pasando?

CLASE Venta

```
public class Venta
    {
        public int NumeroRemision { get; set; }
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaVenta { get; set; }
        public string MetodoPago { get; set; }
        public int IdSucursal { get; set; }
        public int IdPersonal { get; set; }
        public bool Cancelada { get; set; }
        public string Comentario { get; set; }
    }
```

APLICACION DE CONSOLA:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string conexion = @"server=DESKTOP-1VONR57\SQLEXPRESS;database=MAGABD;uid=MagaManager;password=Password1;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";

            using (var dep = new SqlTableDependency<Venta>(conexion))
            {
                dep.OnChanged += Changed;
                dep.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Presione una tecla para salir");
                Console.ReadKey();

                dep.Stop();
            }
        }

        public static void Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<Venta> e)
        {
            var changedEntity = e.Entity;

            Console.WriteLine("Tipo de operacion: " + e.ChangeType);
            Console.WriteLine("Campo1: " + changedEntity.NumeroRemision);
        }
    }
```

WINDOWS FORMS

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LlenarComboImpresoras();
            LlenarCmbSucursal();
            LlenarCmbCliente();
            LlenarCmbMetodoPago();
            LlenarCmbVendedor();
            txtNumeroRemision.Focus();
            CargarVentas();
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

            panel1.Location = new Point(
            this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - panel1.Size.Width / 2,
            this.ClientSize.Height / 2 - panel1.Size.Height / 2);
            panel1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;

            lblFechaInic.Visible = false;
            dtpFechaInic.Visible = false;
            lblFechaFin.Visible = false;
            dtpFechaFin.Visible = false;

            grdDetalleVenta.Visible = false;
            bttnImprimir.Enabled = false;
            grdVenta.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            grdDetalleVenta.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;

            IniciarSqlTableDependency(); //<--------- AQUI LO LLAMO
        }
        private void IniciarSqlTableDependency()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var dependency = new SqlTableDependency<Venta>(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion1"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    dependency.OnChanged += Changed; //Cuando detecte cambios en la tabla ejecutara la funcion Changed();
                    dependency.Start();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                recurso.MensajeError("Error al tratar de conectar en tiempo real con la base de datos");
            }
        }

        private void Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<Venta> e)
        {
            var changedEntity = e.Entity;

            if(e.ChangeType == TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.Enums.ChangeType.Insert)
            {
                CargarVentas();
            }
        }
```

- En la aplicación de windows forms la cadena la conexión la obtengo desde App.config pero es exactamente la misma.
- En la aplicación de Windows forms llamo a la función CargarVentas() que llena un DataGridView con la info de todas las ventas. Esta función funciona bien así que tampoco es error de la función.

ACTUALIZACION: Me suscribí al evento OnStatusChanged en la aplicación de WindowsForms y arroja los siguientes mensajes:
- Status: Starting
- Status: Started
- Status: StopDueToCancellation

También me he suscrito al evento OnError pero este no arroja nada. Sigo sin saber que es lo que pasa.

Comment: en la app de consola lo estas llamando del main y en el winforms de donde lo estas llamando?

Comment: @RamiroBarone Justo al iniciar el formulario, ya estuve debuggeando y confirmé que IniciarSqlTableDependency() se ejecuta correctamente, es solo que el evento no se dispara. Ya actualice el codigo de windows forms para que se aprecie en donde lo llamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al fin pude resolverlo.

Por algún motivo (y esto solo me sucede en windows forms) si en una misma función creo la conexion entre SqlTableDependency y la BD, y ejecuto la función Start() de SqlTableDependency, el estatus pasa por los siguientes estados:

1. Status: Starting
2. Status: Started
3. Status: StopDueToCancellation

La solución fue crear una función específicamente solo para crear la conexión entre SqlTableDependency y la BD, y otra función solo para iniciarla. De esta manera las salidas de estatus en consola fueron:
1. Status: Starting
2. Status: Started
3. Status: WaitingForNotification

- Antes

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LlenarComboImpresoras();
            LlenarCmbSucursal();
            LlenarCmbCliente();
            LlenarCmbMetodoPago();
            LlenarCmbVendedor();
            txtNumeroRemision.Focus();
            CargarVentas();
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

            panel1.Location = new Point(
            this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - panel1.Size.Width / 2,
            this.ClientSize.Height / 2 - panel1.Size.Height / 2);
            panel1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;

            lblFechaInic.Visible = false;
            dtpFechaInic.Visible = false;
            lblFechaFin.Visible = false;
            dtpFechaFin.Visible = false;

            grdDetalleVenta.Visible = false;
            bttnImprimir.Enabled = false;
            grdVenta.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            grdDetalleVenta.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;

            IniciarSqlTableDependency(); //<--------- AQUI LO LLAMO
        }
        private void IniciarSqlTableDependency()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var dependency = new SqlTableDependency<Venta>(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion1"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    dependency.OnChanged += Changed; //Cuando detecte cambios en la tabla ejecutara la funcion Changed();
                    dependency.Start();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                recurso.MensajeError("Error al tratar de conectar en tiempo real con la base de datos");
            }
        }

        private void Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<Venta> e)
        {
            var changedEntity = e.Entity;

            if(e.ChangeType == TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.Enums.ChangeType.Insert)
            {
                CargarVentas();
            }
        }
```

- SOLUCION

```
private SqlTableDependency<Venta> dependency;

public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LlenarComboImpresoras();
            LlenarCmbSucursal();
            LlenarCmbCliente();
            LlenarCmbMetodoPago();
            LlenarCmbVendedor();
            txtNumeroRemision.Focus();
            CargarVentas();
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

            panel1.Location = new Point(
            this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - panel1.Size.Width / 2,
            this.ClientSize.Height / 2 - panel1.Size.Height / 2);
            panel1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;

            lblFechaInic.Visible = false;
            dtpFechaInic.Visible = false;
            lblFechaFin.Visible = false;
            dtpFechaFin.Visible = false;

            grdDetalleVenta.Visible = false;
            bttnImprimir.Enabled = false;
            grdVenta.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            grdDetalleVenta.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;

            CrearSqlTableDependency();
            IniciarSqlTableDependency();
        }

        private void CrearSqlTableDependency()
        {
            try
            {

                using (dependency = new SqlTableDependency<Venta>(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion1"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    dependency.OnChanged += Changed; //Cuando detecte cambios en la tabla ejecutara la funcion Changed();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                recurso.MensajeError("Error al tratar de conectar en tiempo real con la base de datos");
            }
        }

        private void IniciarSqlTableDependency()
        {
            dependency.Start();
        }

        private void Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<Venta> e)
        {
            var changedEntity = e.Entity;

            if(e.ChangeType == TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.Enums.ChangeType.Insert)
            {
                CargarVentas();
            }
        }
```